# C++ templates and function resolution

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a problem I stumbled accross when refactoring some code and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    init(x);
  }

  T x;
};

void init(int& i)
{
  i = 42;
}

int main()
{
  Foo<int> foo;
  std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile - neither with GCC or with Clang. The function `init` called in Foo's constructor is not declared. In this toy example, this could be solved by moving the function itself ahead of the template. However, in a more complex context, this may not work. Originally, I intended to use overloads of `init` to allow some setup for the classes used in the template.

I assumee that in this context `init` is a non-dependend name - even though the argument of the function call depends on the template parameter (which was odd for me at first). Is there a way to trick it to also consider function definitions defined *after* the template itself?

I know that I can use template specialization (which was in the original code in the first place, but I wanted to replace it with simpler overloads):

```
template<typename>
struct Initializer;

template<>
struct Initializer<int>
{
  static void init(int& i)
  {
    i = 42;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work with function overloads as well? I know, `boost::serialization` also relies on function overloads for custom types, but I did not really find where and how they implemented that.

Comment: Can't you just **declare** the function before using it?

Comment: Calling `init()` functions within constructors - especially member functions - is normally a bad idea, Alternatives include delegated constructors, even CRTP can help. You might get better help on the code review site.

Comment: The problem is obvious... init is not a method of the class but a regular function. Move it ABOVE the class to have it be recognized or make it a method of the class by moving init inside it.

Comment: To extend @Bathsheba 's comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm (Construction failures: Objects that never were)

Comment: This is a simplified version of the original problem. Think of `T` as some kind of container class and init should prepopulate it with some values specific to the usage in `Foo`. The point is, that users should be allowed to provide both new *containers* and new implementations of `init` for the specific container. However, the specific prepopulation for `Foo` is not generic enough to put in `T` right away.

Comment: Looks like CRTP to me, or even a problem you can solve with *concepts*.

Comment: 1) CRTP and static polymorphism, 2) initializer-strategy-functions using std::function<...>, 3) making a virtual method and providing a protected "getInternalContainer() : T"-method to access the specifically typed container in init... There are many many ways to do this :D

Comment: Your problem is also that `int`is not a class and no ADL is done for it, replacing `int` by custom class works: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79a5432447e0c82).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the ordering problem by calling through a template function object - in the same way that `boost::hash` finds the ADL-function `hash_value(x)`.

This works because the expansion of the template is deferred until the point of first use:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {

    struct XX {

        friend void init(XX&);
    };
}

namespace B {

    struct YY {
        friend void init(YY&);

    };
}

/// default case - call init on T found by ADL
template<class T>
struct call_init
{
    void operator()(T& o) const {
        init(o);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    auto initialiser = call_init<decltype(this->x)>();
    initialiser(this->x);
  }

  T x;
};

void init(int& x) {
    x = 2;
}

// special case, initialise an int
template<> struct call_init<int>
{
    void operator()(int& x) const {
        init(x);
    }
};


int main()
{
  Foo<int> foo;
  Foo<A::XX> foox;
  Foo<B::YY> fooy;
  std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand correctly that for each new type defined after the template class I have to provide the overload of `init()` as well as the specialized template for `call_init`?

Comment: @rocktale not if you define the free function `init` in the same namespace of each class just after the class definition itself (see my examples in namespaces `A` and `B`). The reason your code does not work is that `init(int)` has not been declared by the time the expansion of `Foo<int>` takes place. If it were `Foo<AnythingElse>` you'd have had to have defined `AnythingElse` so you may as well have declared void `init(AnythingElse&)` at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is also that `int`is not a class and no ADL is done for it, replacing `int` by custom class works:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { init(x); }

  T x;
};

struct C
{
    int i = 0;    
};

void init(C& c) { c.i = 42; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79a5432447e0c82).

To allow to works for primitive type as `int`, you have to introduce some custom type:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { init(x, tag<T>{}); }

  T x;
};

void init(int& i, tag<int>) { i = 42; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef21ab14a0138b4c)